# Question mark in PHP CURL response

Tags: php, curl, encoding, character-encoding

i want to use one site with API,
i have this code:

```
$ch=curl_init('http://example.com/?api=**');
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('text/plain;charset=UTF-8') ,
);

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$results=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($results);
```

but i see `?` instead of some characters like `”`, `»` .
i checked source page and charset is utf-8..
what is problem?

Comment: just because the source page is utf 8, doesn't mean what you're outputting is utf-8. what if your webserver is sending an iso-8859-1 instead to the browser you're viewing results in?

Comment: how can i know if webserver encoding is utf-8?

Comment: check your browser. e.g. firefox's "tools -> page info". it'll say what encoding it's been told to use.

Comment: that is utf-8 but page info show me webserver response encoding or my page encoding?

Answer (score 9):

I guess you missed the option **CURLOPT_ENCODING**

Please try following code.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/?api=**');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
$results = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($results);
```